# Google Indexed demo site with same content

Tags: seo, google-index, noindex

I have two server one is production `abc.com` other `demo.abc.com` problem is Google has indexed the demo server as well.

What is fastest possible fix to it and to remove it from Google index?

What harm it has given to my live site and is that possible to recover in future?

Thanks

Comment: Just add <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> to your demo site..

Comment: I have added as well as robot.txt. How soon it will be fixed? also what damage has done? what if I close down the who demo domain or delete it, which one of these is best solution for it?